# Overly strict [-Wrange-loop-construct] in gcc-12?

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, copy-elision

I have just upgraded to GCC/G++-12.2(with the Debian12 official apt repo) from gcc-10.5.0,
and recompiled my old codes.

g++-12 gave me a lot of warnings like this:

> my_source.cpp:60:25: warning: loop variable 'aaa' creates a copy from
> type 'bbb' [-Wrange-loop-construct]

The source code looks like this:

```
std::set<int16_t> bbb;
for( const auto aaa : bbb ) 
    do_something( aaa );
```

I know I can eliminate it, if I change code into this:

```
std::set<int16_t> bbb;
for( const auto& aaa : bbb ) 
    do_something( aaa );
```

But that will make my code a little weird.
In the fact the size of the variable aaa is very tiny(2 bytes), and I never received such a warning with g++-9 and g++-10 before.

I know its meaning, but I think it is a little overly strict, isn't it?

I found this [old post](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94695) discussed similar problem, some one said this warning should **NOT** occurs if the size less than 64 bits.

Is this a bug of gcc-12? or I made some mistake?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/Yqd7TzGfn)